# Why does JSON-encoded POST data appear in raw_post_data but not POST

Tags: python, django

I am able to parse the following using django's `request.POST`:

```
>>> r = requests.POST(url, data={'name': 'david'})

# in view
name = request.POST.get('name') # 'david'
```

However, if I encode that data as json, I'm not able to get it and I have to use `request.body`:

```
>>> r = requests.POST(url, data=json.dumps({'name': 'david'}))

# in view
name = request.POST.get('name') # empty string
name = request.body.get('name') # 'david'
```

Why doesn't django parse the POST data here if it's in json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.POST` is meant to access conventional html form data, and `request.body` for all other formats (xml, json, etc.). `raw_post_data` is deprecated in newer django versions, it's successor is `request.body`. Also, you would have to deserialize the incoming json data before accessing it even through `request.body` , e.g.: `json.loads(request.body)`

More information can be found about both `HttpRequest.body` and `HttpRequest.POST` in the official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body